# Questions regarding change of basis and eigenvalues / eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I started looking at change of basis and had some question how it ties into eigenvalues/eigevectors.

1. If $T:R^n \to R^n, T(x) = Ax$, are eigenvalue/eigenvectors $A$ only defined (or only make sense) if the same basis is used to define the coordinates of vectors in both the domain and target space (i.e. the standard basis)? Otherwise I think it’s possible for a vector's coordinates to be scaled by the transformation but still change direction?
2. For the same matrix $A$, assuming it is diagonlizable ($A = X\Lambda X^{-1}$),  is $X$ a change of basis matrix that takes a vector whose coordinates are defined in terms of the eigenbasis to the basis (not necessarily standard) for which $T$ is defined? If so, is the computation $y = X^{-1}AXx$ basically applying the transformation on $x$ to produce $y$, where the $X^{-1}$ and $X$ are added so both input and output vectors has coordinates in terms of the eigenbasis?

Comment: The matrix $A$ representing a linear transformation depends on the bases chosen for domain and range, so of course the eigenvalues & eigenvectors of the matrix also depend on the choice of bases. But the transformation $T$ does not depend on the choice of bases, so its eigenvectors and eigenvalues don't depend on those choices. But the way you represent those eigenvectors does depend on the choices. Perhaps working through an example will help you understand.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish a vector from its representation as a coordinate tuple w/r some basis. An eigenvector of $T$ is a vector that’s mapped onto a multiple of itself. That vector and associated eigenvalue exist independent of any choice of basis. How that vector is _represented_ as a coordinate tuple (and $T$’s representation by a matrix), on the other hand, is certainly dependent on the choice of basis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was thinking of a weird example where the vectors in the domain of $T$ has coordinates defined by one basis (say $\beta_1$) and vectors in the image has coordinates based on a different basis (say $\beta_2$), both of $R^n$. In this case, would I have to multiply one side of $Ax = \lambda x$ by a change of basis matrix, such as the right side by $M$ if $M$ takes a vector with coordinates in $\beta_1$ to its equivalent coordinates in $\beta_2$?

Comment: Yes, if you want to find eigenstuff when you have a different basis for the domain than for the codomain, then you have to multiply by a change of basis matrix, which amounts to the same thing as using the same basis for domain and codomain.